# Allure Report html generated blank

Tags: allure

I am doing a POC to implement the Allure report on Maven with TestNG. I am successfully able to implement it but the report generated is blank without any info about the successful build.

Please find my POM file below.

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.org.cboe</groupId>
<artifactId>allurePOC</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<!-- Project information and dependencies -->
<name>allurePOC</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <jetty.http.port>9000</jetty.http.port>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <allure.version>1.4.24.RC3</allure.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Allure dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- Project Build information and dependencies -->

<build>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>

            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javac.exe</executable>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                <!-- <properties> <property> <name>listener</name> <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value> 
                    </property> </properties> -->
            </configuration>


        </plugin>

        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppSourceDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}/site/allure-results
                </webAppSourceDirectory>
                <httpConnector>
                    <port>${jetty.http.port}</port>
                </httpConnector>
                <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>

<!-- Project reporting -->

<reporting>

    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportDirectory> ${project.build.directory}/site/allure-results</reportDirectory>

                <!-- <resultsDirectory></resultsDirectory> -->

            </configuration>

        </plugin>



    </plugins>

</reporting>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add aspectj-weaver as javaagent.See [FAQ-and-Troubleshooting](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/wiki/FAQ-and-Troubleshooting):

> You didn't specify the -javaagent JVM argument. This is mandatory when
>   working with steps, attachments and parameters, because we're using
>   AspectJ to process them.
>
> Solution:: make sure the JVM is being launched with -javaagent
>   path/to/aspectj-weaver.jar. See the example on how this is done with
>   Maven.